# Variable inherit to class from parent

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's take main script with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cl1
import cl2

A = cl1.First()
A.one()

B = cl2.Second()
B.two()

print('\nRep from First class: %sRep from Second class: %s\n' % (A.rep1, B.rep2))
```

`First` class file is:

```
class First:

    def one(self):

        self.rep1 = 'Rep1.\n'
```

And `Second` class file contains:

```
from cl1 import First

class Second(First):

    def two(self):
        self.rep2 = 'Rep2'
```

How can I access variable named `rep1` in class `First` from class `Second`?

I mean - something like:

from cl1 import First

```
class Second(First):

    def two(self):
        self.rep2 = 'Rep2'
        self.l = First()
        self.l.one()
        print('From First: %s' % self.l.rep1)
```

This will work - but I just again create `First` class object, thus - this is not inheritance:

```
$ ./main.py
From First: Rep1.


Rep from First class: Rep1.
Rep from Second class: Rep2
```

I'd like to use something like:

```
from cl1 import First

class Second(First):

    def two(self):
        self.rep2 = 'Rep2'
        self.rep1 = First.rep1
        print('From Second: %sFrom First: %s' % (self.rep2, self.rep1)
```

Python 2.7

P.S. I tried "play" with `super(Second, self)` and so on - but unsuccessful.

Comment: It's generally bad form to initialise instance attributes outside of `__init__`; this leaves you vulnerable to `AttributeError`s until the appropriate method is called.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special. Just accessing `self.rep1` from within a method of `Second` will give you the value. Of course, the value still needs to be set in that specific object, so if you have `ob = Second()`, you first have to call `ob.one()`.

You could try something like:

```
def Second(First):
    def two(self):
        self.one()
        self.rep2 = 'Rep2'
        print(self.rep1, self.rep2) # this will access the value set by one()
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that `rep1` won't exist at least you first the method `one()`.
You can do this:

```
class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one()
    def one(self):
        self.rep1 = 'Rep1.\n'

class Second(First):
    def two(self):
        self.rep2 = 'Rep2'
        self.rep1 = self.rep1
        print('From Second: %sFrom First: %s' % (self.rep2, self.rep1))
```

You can simply access to `rep1` as if it were defined in the `Second` class **because of inheritance**.